# Is it possible to subscribe to an event when a console window gets closed?

Tags: c#, .net, events, console-application

I have a console application; the following hunk of code is the main part that executes:

```
this.service.Start(args);
Console.WriteLine("Service started; press any key to kill.");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Read();
this.service.Cease();
```

The key here is that the service shuts down after a key is pressed in the console window.  However, if the console window is 'x'd out using the red X in the top right of the window, `this.service.Cease()` is never called.

I tried hooking on to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`, but it didn't seem to work.  Are there any alternatives, or am I stuck?

Comment: You can try this: http://geekswithblogs.net/mrnat/archive/2004/09/23/11594.aspx

Comment: What is the class of the service object? I am not sure what you are using... You may be able to check the status of the parent process from within the service. If you are using the service controller though this will not work.

Comment: If you were using Windows Forms instead of Console Application, you could override WndProc method like this: *protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x0010)
                MessageBox.Show("terminating");

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }*

Comment: The comment from @mellamokb is probably the way to go. However, you might be able to do the same thing with the `Console.CancelKeyPress` event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx. I don't recall if the event is raised when the window is closed with the 'X'.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that you can show a hidden window and use its exit message, but other than that you're stuck. You can make Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break work correctly:

```
        using (var waiter = new ManualResetEventSlim())
        {
            Console.TreatControlCAsInput = false;
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) => { waiter.Set(); eventArgs.Cancel = false; };
            Console.WriteLine(@"Press Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break for a clean exit...");
            waiter.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
        }
```